# mysql Trigger to different host

Tags: mysql, triggers

I can use mysql trigger to same server and same host. Can I trigger in to different host. Is there any other method to do that.

```
Localhost -> 10.1.2.220
```

Comment: Basically no, but... are you using replication or why would you want this, could you add a bit more info about the situation? Maybe we can suggest an alternate solution with more information.

Comment: @xception It has some transactions on my main mysql database. I need to change the status of different (Database) system with my transaction. thats why I need this.

Comment: There are many alternative solutions for this issue. Like SOAP..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Triggers are possible to used on same hosted site. Definer of the trigger can be changes as you wish but difficult to handle with remote host.

Using of PHP SOAP client and Server is suitable to prevent your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it myself, but take a look at the FEDERATED storage engine for MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-storage-engine.html